# C++ how to use a function in a dll that requires an address

Tags: c++, dll

I would like to call a function inside a dll, so I have been following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810279.aspx) tutorial, which seemed both the most straightforward (gave clear code examples and explanations) and the most backwards compatible (November 1999) code. The dll I want to call uses functions which require compound datatypes, so I defined those in my code. I was following the tutorial and all seemed to be going well until I saw that one of the demanded arguments in the function was an address. When I tried to put in an address in the callback declaration I get an error ("expected a type specifier").

The dll I'm using was not coded by me, so I'm using the .def file and a source file which uses these same functions as proof that the functions exist and as reference on how to use them respectively.

How can I use these functions in my C++ code, assuming I'm reading the files properly (even if I'm not the error should be run-time not compile-time) assuming the dll is already on the target computer (like I said, I didn't code it)?

Thanks for any help and sorry if this is a noobish question.

Comment: I have a feeling if you are creating a .dll all functions must be declared as **extern**

Comment: What do you mean by "putting the address in the callback declaration"?. Also, are the DLL functions in C, or C++?

Comment: @ArifBurhan OK I will look into that but the tutorial gives no mention to extern for explicit dlls and I am not coding the dll. @MarkNunberg `typedef datatype(CALLBACK* func1)(compdatatype, &compdatatype, otherdatatype);`. It needs the address because that's where it writes the output and it officially returns success or failure. I believe they are in C because the code I'm referencing is C.

Comment: `&compdatatype`?  Don't you mean `compdatatype*`?

Comment: @TonyD Wow I'm such an idiot... thanks that fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: Sure - no worries.